# How to use the ng-repeat $index variable in an AngularJs expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm generating a lot of HTML with ng-repeat. I rely on the $index variable in order to index data in my controller.

I do alot of stuff like

```
 ng-submit="validateExistingGuest($index)"
```

In this case, an undetermined number of HTML forms is generated, hence the index.

Problem is, i sometimes need to use this variable inside a different kind of expression. That would look something like that:

```
ng-if= "user{{$index}}.valid"
```

Of course, that doesn't work. I tried ways of constructing that expression, with no success.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: is user{{$index}} the name of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="value in user track by $index"> ... 
  //now you can use the {{$index}}
  <div ng-if="user[$index].valid">Show only if valid!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sheff2k1If the question is answered, you should close the question by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
 ng-if="user[$index].valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the object instead the `$index`?, try

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars" > 
    <p {{car}}></p>
    <button ng-click="buy(car)" > buy </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the index, because i'm generating an unknown number of HTML forms, with a corresponding unknown number of user objects :-)